# Calculating primes: Could this be any faster?

Tags: c++, primes, benchmarking

I've ported a prime-number calculation program from [primes.pyx](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html#primes) to C++ for benchmark purpose.

Since I wrote it in C++, I thought that my program would be faster than the original. However, mine took 25.8 ms at the fastest, while the original took only 1.45 ms on the same machine. I tested 10 times each, but got similar results (25.8~51.7ms vs 1.45~1.47ms). But, why?

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

vector<int> primes(size_t nb_primes)
{
    int n;
    vector<int> p;
    p.reserve(nb_primes);

    n = 2;
    while (p.size() < nb_primes)
    {
        bool other = true;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < p.size(); i++)
        {
            if (n % p[i] == 0)
            {
                other = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (other)
            p.push_back(n);
        n += 1;
    }
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    vector<int> p = primes(1000);
    //for (auto i : p)
    //    cout << i << ' ';

    auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = finish - start;
    std::cout << "Elapsed Time: " << elapsed.count() << " s\n";
}
```

These algorithms are exactly the same, I believe.
Please don't limit the check up to sqrt(n), to achieve a sieve of Eratosthenes.
I need to compare with the original.

One thing I'm worried is the `for ... else` statement in the original.
I borrowed the idea to use the `other` flag from [Username: haccks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693694/is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-for-else-python-loop-in-c).
If you can apply another `for ... else` method, please go ahead.

My Windows 10 machine (i5) spec:
Clock Frequency: 1.60GHz 1.80GHz
Memory: 8.00GB

I wrote the original version on Anaconda Prompt/Python 3.8.
I write the C++ version on Visual Studio 2019.

If you need more information, please ask me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What compiler optimisation options are you using? It completes in 1ms for me with `g++ -O3`.

Comment: You tagged this benchmarking, but how did you benchmark it? What optimizers on what system?

Comment: @gmath I see! Thanks to you, I've just got `Elapsed Time: 0.0014516 s`! Please make it an answer; so I will accept it. Firstly, I was running in `Debug Mode` (sorry). Changing to `Release Mode` made it 2~7ms. Then, I set `Favor Size Or Speed` as `Favor fast code (/Ot)`. It made 1.45ms! Thank you sooo much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some optimizations that can make your code better, even with compiler optimizations turned on:

Pre-allocate the vector and treat it like an array.

Use a variable to keep track of the length.

Putting these together, I found about a 10% increase in speed:

```
vector<int> primes(size_t nb_primes)
{
    vector<int> p(nb_primes,2);
    int n = 2;
    size_t len_p = 0;
    while (len_p < nb_primes)
    {
        bool other = true;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len_p; i++)
        {
            if (n % p[i] == 0)
            {
                other = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (other)
            p[len_p++] = n;
        n += 1;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: You're right, you improved 11.0% on average. In addition, your version is closer to the original since you introduced the variable `len_p`. `vector<int> p(nb_primes,2);` was new to me. It seems it's called [Expression List](https://ncona.com/2019/01/variable-initialization-in-cpp/). I'll learn these techniques. Thank you so much!

/ Primes by me
/ # of Tests: 100
/ Average: 0.00141529
/ Minimum: 0.0012612
/ Maximum: 0.0023088
/ Median: 0.0013155

/ Primes by tinstaafl
/ # of Tests: 100
/ Average: 0.00127456
/ Minimum: 0.0012637
/ Maximum: 0.0016251
/ Median: 0.0012686

Answer (score 1):

**The code is not the cause of the slow down**

> Since I wrote it in C++, I thought that my program would be faster than the original. However, mine took 25.8 ms at the fastest, while the original took only 1.45 ms on the same machine.

I get about 1ms when compiling with `g++ -O3`. So the code is achieves your goal of performing (at least as) well as the `.pyx` code, it must be your compilation options. C++ compilers often do not turn on optimisations by default. When bench-marking code ensure that you are compiling your code with optimisations on.

As you mention there are optimisations that can be applied to the code, such as using `sqrt(n)`, which you won't use because you "need to compare with the original". Your code seems to be already as optimised as the `.pyx`, so any further optimisations may impair the comparison. You could avoid using `using namespace std;`, however, which is not usually recommended as using an entire name space can result in name collisions.

Comment: [This does not provide insight about the code in the question.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) And it does little to improve microbenchmarking skills or know-how.

Comment: @greybeard Perhaps, but it is correct answer to the question asked (Why is my C++ code slower than '.pyx'). And the OP specifically asked *not* to optimise the algorithm past the `.pyx` code. Arguably this is the wrong site to ask the question, but the OP didn't know that till I answered.

Comment: I was the only one to make the observation that the code wasn't the problem.

Comment: That link mentions that short answers are fine, but `using namespace std;` is not recommended I guess.

Comment: @gmatht Upvoted. As you suggested, my compiler optimization options were the main cause of the slowness. Also, thank you for telling me that `using namespace std;` is not recommended. Thank you so much.

Comment: People: If I were you guys, I would downvote **my question**, but not gmatht's answer. He came here to help me, and actually helped me. I didn't notice the compiler optimization options until he let me know. If something is wrong here, it's all my fault.

Comment: @IanHacker It isn't always possible to avoid the XY problem, e.g asking for code optimisation when code isn't the cause; the recommendation is to give enough information to find the real problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In this case you gave a complete working example together with your expected and actual result. Answering this question was fairly easy, so I think this is a relatively good question.